# Unable to store results using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the results using ajax like this

```
$('#category').click(function(event) {

  category = $("input[name='category']:checked").data("id");
  var Html = "";

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}',
      category: category
    },
    url: "{% url 'data_entry' %}",
    success: function(data) {

      console.log(data);

      $.each(data, function(key, object) {
        $.each(object, function(key, values) {
          Html = "<div><label>" + object + "</label>"
          $.each(values, function(key, value) {
            Html += "<div style='float:left'><input name='" + value + "' type='checkbox' value='" + value + "'><span>" + value + "</span></div>"
          });
        });
      });

      console.log(Html)
      $('#attribute').html(Html)
    },
    error: function(response, error) {}
  });
});
```

the results i get is an array that looks like this

```
[Object, Object]
0
:
Object
color
:
Array[3]
0
:
"BLUE"
1
:
"RED"
2
:
"YELLOW"
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array[0]
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
size
:
Array[6]
0
:
"S"
1
:
"M"
2
:
"L"
3
:
"XL"
4
:
"XXL"
5
:
"XXXL"
length
:
6
__proto__
:
Array[0]
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array[0]
```

i am trying to loop through all the values of the array and store it in the variable Html but it shows only the final iteration value ie the values present in size array.what can be wrong and how can i resolve this error.

Comment: As an aside, you need to add `Html += '</div>';` to the end of your `$.each(object, function(key, values))` callback, as you have a `<div>` (`Html = "<div><label>"+object+"</label>"`) which you're not closing.

Comment: how can i get the names of the array like size and color from the javascript object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *resetting* the variable every time you do this:

```
Html = "<div><label>"+object+"</label>"
```

So it's only ever going to have the values from the last iteration of the (outer) loop.  It sounds like you *meant* to append rather than assign:

```
Html += "<div><label>"+object+"</label>"
```

Comment: ohh i got it thanks...also i need to ask how can i get the names of the array like size and color from the javascript object ?

Answer (score 0):

To use data as json you should add `dataType: "json"` to you ajax request

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   data: data,
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data){
   //now you can use it as json not as a string as you did before, so all your methods will work

   }
})
```